# unable to download files from sftp server using python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

i am writing a python script that helps me download files from sftp server to my local folder.
when i run the script it just downloads the blank document 
i keep on trying but i am failing

i made a sftp server to test the code and the path specified in remote path is server root directory

i giving code below

```
import pysftp

myHostname = "192.168.56.1"
myUsername = "new45"
myPassword = "146515"

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    # Define the file that you want to download from the remote directory
    remoteFilePath = 'C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\ftp\\testfile.txt'

    # Define the local path where the file will be saved
    # or absolute "C:\Users\sdkca\Desktop\TUTORIAL.txt"
    localFilePath = 'C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\ftp2\\textfile.txt'

    sftp.get(remoteFilePath, localFilePath)

# connection closed automatically at the end of the with-block'''
```

please tell me whats the error why is blank file is being downloaded

Comment: The folder is probably root homed on the SFTP server. Try removing the path from the remoteFilePath and just put testfile.txt instead.  If that doesn't do it, then it might be worth it to turn on logging by using the log parameter on CnOpts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to that server using any GUI SFTP client. And observe what path syntax your server is using. It's definitely not `C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\ftp\testfile.txt`. SFTP uses forward slashes. So it can be like `/C:/Users/Simon/Desktop/ftp/testfile.txt`. But even something completely different, particularly if the server or your account are [chrooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

You are probably trying to use the path syntax, which you would have used, were you directly on that target Windows system.  But your SFTP server presents the files using a different path syntax. You need to adhere to that syntax.